# Argument evaluation order between curly braces and parentheses

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, language-lawyer, c++17

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

uint32_t func() { return rand() % 10; }

struct A {
  uint32_t _x, _y, _z;
  A(uint32_t x, uint32_t y, uint32_t z) : _x(x), _y(y), _z(z) {}
};

int main() {
  A a{func(), func(), func()};
  //A a(func(), func(), func());

  printf("%d %d %d\n", a._x, a._y, a._z);
  return 0;
}
```

`GCC 9.1` and `MSVC 19.22.27905` will both print a different order when using curly braces or parentheses.
`Clang 8.0.0` will print the same order for both cases.

I can´t find anything in the standard about it, is it in the standard or is it up to the compiler which orders it evaluates the input argument?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The order is only guaranteed for braced-init-list, [[dcl.init.list]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.init.list#4):

(emphasis mine)

> Within the initializer-list of a braced-init-list, the initializer-clauses, including any that result from pack expansions ([temp.variadic]), **are evaluated in the order in which they appear**. That is, every value computation and side effect associated with a given initializer-clause is sequenced before every value computation and side effect associated with any initializer-clause that follows it in the comma-separated list of the initializer-list. [ Note: **This evaluation ordering holds regardless of the semantics of the initialization; for example, it applies when the elements of the initializer-list are interpreted as arguments of a constructor call, even though ordinarily there are no sequencing constraints on the arguments of a call.** — end note ]

On the other hand, [order of evaluation of arguments in a function call](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/intro.abstract#3) is [unspecified](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub#Explanation).

> *unspecified behavior* - the behavior of the program varies between implementations and the conforming implementation is not required to document the effects of each behavior. For example, [order of evaluation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order), whether identical [string literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) are distinct, the amount of array allocation overhead, etc. Each unspecified behavior results in one of a set of valid results.

Comment: Note that, prior to C++17, it was possible for (subexpressions of) different arguments to be **interleaved**, such that `f(std::unique_ptr<T>(new T),std::unique_ptr<T>(new T))` could leak one object if the construction of the other failed.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Clang evaluates arguments in this declaration

```
A a( func(), func(), func() );
```

from left to right. While the other compilers evaluate them in the order from right to left.

The order of the evaluation of arguments is unspecified.

As for the curly braces then the evaluation is strictly determined from left to right and evaluation of each expression is sequenced.

Comment: @NicolBolas Well it can be said sequenced.:)

Comment: Is the code in your answer supposed to be with parentheses instead of braces?

Comment: @L.F. Somebody changed the code without making me know.